# Game loop using threads and synchronization

Tags: java, multithreading, synchronization, game-engine

I've been muddling through the internet and my own code in an attempt to write a game-loop I'm satisfied with (I'm picky).

I implemented DeWitter's loop but decided I didn't like interpolation for many different reasons. I don't find it a practical solution.

Anyway, I would like to create two threads, one for updating and one for rendering. I would regulate their execution with minimum and maximum looping intervals and a call to sleep. Then all I would have to deal with would be synchronization.

Is this a reasonable loop? Any major problems that would arise?

It seems to be the only implementation I can think of so far that would give me all the things I'm looking for.

Comment: Hello welcome to stack overflow. This question is more appropriate to http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/. regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea of running dual threads like this is supposedly to increase performance but in reality implementing it is extremely difficult.

Obviously you can't have both threads accessing the same objects and variables at the same time, so you setup synchronization to make either thread wait it's turn but then why bother having dual threads at all? It's self-defeating.

Unless your game is truly massive and eats cpu like nobody's business, then I'd just execute logic and rendering on a single thread, profile it's performance and fine tune it.

Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Yeah that makes a lot of sense. Thanks for the input. Back to endlessly tweaking I go!